# How to turn on the Autocomplete mode in irb mode?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have configured AutoComplete to help me when writing Ruby programs, but in irb window, it is off. How do I turn it on and keep it that way in subsequent Emacs starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in your config something like:

```
 (defun my-inf-ruby-mode-hook ()
    (set (make-local-variable 'ac-auto-start) 2)
    (set (make-local-variable 'ac-auto-show-menu) t)
   )
 (add-hook 'inf-ruby-mode-hook 'my-inf-ruby-mode-hook)
```

And I think, that you'll also need to setup `ac-sources` variable in this hook, so it will use ruby dictionaries...

Comment: Ok, so the name of the mode hook would be 'inferior-ruby-mode-hook. Otherwise, it's still resisting, I'm trying to get it running. Anyway thanks for getting me started.

Comment: OK, so I will make another question about the last remaining problem, which is how do I refer to only Ruby mode buffers in `ac-sources` statement.

Comment: You can explicitly `set ac-sources` for ruby mode via `ruby-mode-hook`, and set `ac-sources` to `nil` for all other modes via `setq-default` during load