# In Emacs irb (inferior-ruby-mode), how to make Autocomplete honor words from Ruby mode buffers?

Tags: ruby, emacs, autocomplete

While [setting up autocomplete in Emacs irb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465151) (inferior-ruby-mode), I ran into a problem of not being able to add only Ruby mode buffers as AC sources. I can eg. add files in the current directory by

```
(setq ac-sources '(ac-source-files-in-current-dir))
```

or I can add all buffers (which I resorted to in the end) by

```
(setq ac-sources '(ac-source-words-in-all-buffer))
```

but what I would really like is to only add *Ruby* mode buffers. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look to `ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers`... We can re-use this approach to build our own completion sources, for example:

```
 (ac-define-source words-in-ruby-buffers
   '((init . ac-update-word-index)
     (candidates . (ac-word-candidates
                     (lambda (buffer)
                       (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer) 'ruby-mode))))))
```

will give us `ac-source-words-in-ruby-buffers` completion source.

P.S. I hadn't tested it, but it should work ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not think this will work, or otherwise Emacs would have to magically consider inferior-ruby-mode same as ruby-mode. I will try it tomorow for the peace of mind.

Comment: Wow, what are you, an Autocomplete head developer?

Comment: You are amazing, if you were not 10k user, I'd investigate how does on award bounty post factum :) Thanks again, Emacs, while being an excellent tool, is still a bit too much for me to handle (I'm a biologist).

Comment: no, I'm rarely using auto-complete, but I'm working with Emacs more than 15 years, so can read code quickly ;-) If you'll have a questions, don't hesitate to contact me directly (via e-mail)...