# When using `gets` in Ruby for input, is there any way to get command history?

Tags: ruby

I have a CLI app which uses `gets` repeatedly, in a loop.

For example,

```
$app > what is your command?
$me  > help
$app > ... print the man page ...
$app > what is your command?
```

It's not an IRB console, so I can't get command history using the up/down arrows.

I thought about making a data structure (i.e. array) to log commands and bind some `gets` input to move through it.

I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

The command to navigate up/down in the history should not require a press of `enter`

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: There is no way to make `gets` behave this way. You would need to use one of the many terminal libraries for Ruby.

Comment: You are contradictory. If you do not press enter, it is not a `gets` input (although it can be other types of input).

Comment: @meager, any idea which of the terminal libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started looking into tab completion and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876024/how-to-write-a-ruby-command-line-app-that-supports-tab-completion) which recommends using `readline` from stdlib.

I discovered that  it also supports command history.