# Extracting list of common words within Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, processing-efficiency

I hope that I'll be able to articulate this clearly, please forgive me if not.

Right now I've got an array of strings with essentially file-paths, like described here:

```
2.1.7 :002 > a
 => ["stuff/things/oranges", "stuff/things/bananas", "stuff/others/upside", "stuff/others/down", "stuff/what/who", "how/what/when", "how/what/time", "a/b/c", "a/d/c"]
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is something along the lines of tab-completion functionality with this information.

Lets say that I've already typed `stuff/` and hit tab. I'd like to be able to pull the values `things`, `others`, and `what` out and throw them into their own array, since they're the unique next possible values. Then after that if I have `stuff/things`, then I'd like to have the values `oranges` and `bananas` possible. So if we this can be made to be efficient and recursive, that would be ideal.

It should be known that the next values in the chain (`things`, `others`, `what`) aren't known, so it needs to be programic to find those.

The issue I'm having is that this original `a` array will have hundreds, if not a few thousand entries. So efficiency is definitely a key player here.

Thank you for looking at this and I hope it makes sense. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what have you already tried.

Comment: @mudasobwa I don't have anything yet, I'm asking more to help wrap my head around a good way to move forward since I can't seem to come up with anything

Comment: I would recommend you to implement a tree structure, where nodes will be possible dirs and files.

Comment: @ilya I had that idea, but in my case there aren't exactly directories or files, it just looks like there is. So I'm still stuck with information from `a`

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Your question is premature. On Stack Overflow we expect you to have researched and then show where you searched and explain why that didn't help, or, to have written code and then write a detailed question about a specific problem. You're asking us to tell you ways to do this, but that's too broad, and explaining how to do that would amount to writing a tutorial if we write detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking grep might be useful.

```
a = ["stuff/things/oranges", "stuff/things/bananas", "stuff/others/upside", "stuff/others/down", "stuff/what/who", "how/what/when", "how/what/time", "a/b/c", "a/d/c"]    

a.grep /\Astuff/
=> ["stuff/things/oranges", "stuff/things/bananas", "stuff/others/upside", "stuff/others/down", "stuff/what/who"]

a.grep /\Astuff\/things/
=> ["stuff/things/oranges", "stuff/things/bananas"]
```

Comment: You're not exactly wrong, but, I guess I should state that the next values such as things are not going to be known, so there needs to be a programic way

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean.  You don't know the search query ahead of time? Or you want to be able to type `stuff/t` and then get the result of `a.grep /stuff\/t/` ? In the web you would re query the server with a the new query string (each time you enter a new char) and re-evaluate the list.  But you can only do that because you can track the event of a new char being added to the string and then make an ajax call to re-query.  Im not really sure you can track that event in the ruby console

Comment: Fails on `"stuff/things/stuff"`.

Comment: Well I mean, sure I /know/ what possibilities there are that could come next, but I can't just say a.grep /stuff\/things/ because I'm not sure if things is what I want. I want to grab the options out of the main array.

Comment: This would be a correct answer if you’d put a beginning of line matcher into regexp: `a.grep /stuff/` ⇒ `a.grep /\Astuff/`. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @mudasobwa nice catch :)

Comment: @Chiggins How can you evaluate an option out of the array when the array hasn't been returned yet? You need to supply the argument `/stuff/` to the message `grep` that is being sent to the collection `a`.  You can search for the next option you want and then pass it as an argument to `grep` again, either to the original array or the resulting array.  If you want something like a command-like script maybe you can combine both grep and this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876024/how-to-write-a-ruby-command-line-app-that-supports-tab-completion

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Readline, which is how Bash and other shells implement autocompletion:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html

This tutorial covers it in great depth:

http://bogojoker.com/readline/