# Capistrano 3 execute arbitrary command on remote server

Tags: ruby, capistrano3

Capistrano 3 does not use command `cap env shell` anymore.

Now we should use `cap env console`

But it is not interactive and we can not use for example arrow keys for history or autocompletion on `tab` button

And what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to write your own little rake task to do it. Use `readline` gem
First of all thanks to follow materials:

1. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tab-completion-in-gnu-readline-ruby-edition
2. [How to write a Ruby command line app that supports tab completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876024/how-to-write-a-ruby-command-line-app-that-supports-tab-completion)

```
desc "Remote console" 
task :console do
  require 'readline'
  # https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tab-completion-in-gnu-readline-ruby-edition

  host_args = (ENV['HOSTS'] || '').split(',').map { |r| r.to_sym }
  role_args = (ENV['ROLES'] || '').split(',').map { |r| r.to_sym }

  LIST = `ls /usr/bin`.split("\n").sort + `ls /bin`.split("\n").sort

  comp = proc { |s| LIST.grep(/^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/) }

  Readline.completion_append_character = " "
  Readline.completion_proc = comp

  while line = Readline.readline('cap> ', true)
    begin
      next if line.strip.empty?
      exec_cmd(line, host_args, role_args)
    rescue StandardError => e
      puts e
      puts e.backtrace
    end
  end
end

def exec_cmd(line, host_args, role_args)
  line = "RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} #{line}" if fetch(:stage)
  cmd = "bash -lc '#{line}'"
  puts "Final command: #{cmd}"
  if host_args.any?
    on hosts host_args do
      execute cmd
    end
  elsif role_args.any?
    on roles role_args do
      execute cmd
    end
  else
    on roles :all do
      execute cmd
    end
  end
end
```

And do what you want with it, cheers! =))